# Prolog allowing multiple query argument orders

Tags: function, prolog

I'm working on some homework in Prolog and I have to use something similar enough to:

rules:

```
brothers(a,b)
brothers(c,d)
```

and I have to implement the ability to query `brothers(b,a)` and get true without having duplicates in the database.

I thought about using: `brothers(X,Y):- brothers(Y,X)` but it will just be infinitely recursive. I'm not sure what else I can do since both names must be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to break the infinite recursion! This can be done in various ways:

1) Ordering
Create your database so in each `brother(X,Y)` rule `X>Y`.
Then, add a rule `brother(X,Y):- Y>X, brother(Y,X).`

2) Wrapper predicate
`brother(X,Y):- brother_facts(X,Y) ; brother_facts(Y,X).`

3) Tabling
Possible if you use XSB (or some other prolog implementation that supports it).
Tabling is a bit like memoization and will break the loop

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing number 2 about the same time as you posted it, hope thing it fits with the guidelines.

Number 1 sounds really interesting though, I never thought about it like that.